# How does one core get work in a multi-core system?

Tags: operating-system, cpu

Is it the Operating System who delegates any job to core?

What is that specific algorithm or a way, on which it is decided that the next task will be assigned to which cpu core?

Answer (score 0):

Correct, it is the operating system's responsibility to designate tasks for the CPU to complete, regardless of how many cores it has. It does this via a **scheduling algorithm**, which decides in what order tasks/processes should be executed. In a symmetric multiprocessing environment, the OS views each core as an independent, identical CPU and therefore schedules them individually. When several cores are available, there are a couple important things to keep in mind: 
1. Load balancing- For maximum performance, each core should be performing roughly the same amount of work. 
2. Affinity- Because of caching, it is best (in terms of performance) for processes to complete the entirety of their execution on just one processor. 
These things need to be kept in mind along with the traditional scheduling considerations of priority, fairness etc. Obviously, this topic is far too large for just one post to handle, so here are some resources that go in to further detail:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/operating_system/os_process_scheduling_algorithms.htm
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiple-processor-scheduling-in-operating-system/

Comment: *Load balancing- For maximum performance, each core should be performing roughly the same amount of work.* - That's not true.  If you only have 4 threads active, it's best to leave each thread on the same physical core it was already running on, and leave any other physical cores asleep.  If there's enough work to keep all your CPUs busy, then none of them should be asleep, but migrating tasks between CPU cores just to distribute the work has negative effects: cache misses on the new core.  They all get close to the same temperature so migrating tasks isn't going to let you turbo higher.